# Query to retrieve certain cells on access

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a query for an Excel book that will, when the sheet is activated:

Query all sheets in the book with a few exceptions
Retrieve the values of three cells from each sheet
Post those values to three correlative columns starting from row 4 onwards

At the moment I'm thinking some sort of array type query (stealing from previous work) along the lines of:

```
dim ws as worksheet
dim arrsheets as variant
dim strsheets as string

for each ws in activeworkbook.sheets
if ws.index > 1 and not ws.name like "BETA*" (( and herein lies the first hurdle, I need to add some other exceptions?))
then
sheet.lmdtmonitor(a4)=ws.sheet(b1)
sheet.lmdtmonitor(b4)=ws.sheet(f1)
sheet.lmdtmonitor(c4)=ws.sheet(f2)
```

and then having it loop till it gets to the end, with the a4/b4/c4 above incrementing to a5 > a6 > a7 etc per sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted :)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
```

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = 4

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "FRONT PAGE", "ZON-DOCS", "LMDT Monitor", "Stonegate New World"
            'Do nothing, we're ignoring these sheets
        Case Else
            'Primary: Extract Estate Name from "CurrentSheet.B1" to "LMDT Monitor".ColumnB(starting at Row 4)
            Cells(Lastrow, 2).Value = ws.Cells(1, 2)
            'Primary: Extract Last Modified Time from F1 to monitor sheet Column C
            Cells(Lastrow, 3).Value = ws.Cells(1, 6)
            'Primary: Extract Modified By from F2 to monitor sheet Column D
            Cells(Lastrow, 4).Value = ws.Cells(2, 6)
            'Secondary: Insert Sheet# into Column A
            Cells(Lastrow, 1).Value = ws.CodeName
               Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
    End Select
 Next ws
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I've added code to help you step through each sheet as required `SELECT CASE`- not sure what you want to do with the 3 cells though.  I'll update my answer once I know more.

```
'CORRELATIVE:

'1. so related that each implies or complements the other.
'2. being in correlation; mutually related.
'3. Grammar. answering to or complementing one another and regularly used in association, as either and or, not only and but.
'4. Biology. (of a typical structure of an organism) found in correlation with another.

'.... please explain further as you're code doesn't help here.

'Sheet.lmdtmonitor(a4) = ws.Sheet(b1)
'Sheet.lmdtmonitor(b4) = ws.Sheet(f1)
'Sheet.lmdtmonitor(c4) = ws.Sheet(f2)

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Worksheets will ignore Chart & Macro sheets.
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "ALPHA*", "BETA*"
                'Do nothing, we're ignoring these sheets.
            Case Else
                'Do your correlative stuff with these sheets.

        End Select
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,
Apologies for not getting back to you sooner.
Picking up from where you left off - once the script has clarified if it's a sheet it needs to pay attention to - it then needs to copy the contents of 3 cells from the currently selected sheet into the host sheet.

So for instance, if I have 10 additional sheets outwith the excluded ones. I need the script to copy the data from the 3 cells of the first additional sheet into the first empty row in the monitor sheet, then move onto the next additional sheet. Once complete, the host sheet would then have 3 columns of data.